# how to write data on firebase at three diffrent node at one without closing view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, database-schema

Basically I am checking if some data exist in the firebase database or not using `Database.database().reference().child(“users”).hasChild(“somename”)`
if it has that some name then i want to write to three different node on firebase i.e at sender node at receiver node and at one more node
i am doing this by calling

```
  Database.database().reference().child(“send).childbyautoid.servalue(somename: somevalue)
  Database.database().reference().child(“receiver”).child(“receiverid”).childbyautoid.setvalue(somename: somevalue)
  database.database.reference().child(“all”).childbyautoid.setvalue(somename: somevalue)
```

problem is i am doing it just before closing the view controller
so either i should wait for all of the fire to execute or controller dismisses only after calling one fire
is this a bad design what should i do to close the controller immediately and also get the data at three places on firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform multiple writes in one go by using a multi-location update. In your code that would look something like this:

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
let pushId = rootRef.childByAutoId().key
let updatedUserData = [
  "send/\(pushId)/someName": someValue, 
  "receiver/\(pushId)/someName": someValue,
  "receiver/\(all)/someName": someValue
]
// Do a deep-path update
rootRef.updateChildValues(updatedUserData, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) -> Void in
    if (error) {
        print("Error updating data: \(error.description)")
    }
})
```

The completion handler is then also the place where you'd put code that needs to run when the write is done.

Also see:

- The [blog post announcing multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

Comment: thanks man it works but there is still delay of a jiffy only if i could do anything about it